# Flipping multiple animations along an axis (transform the character from left handed to right handed) ? (For UE5)

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on, unreal-engine

Hello so I did some researches before I post this question but I didnt found any solution for my problem

I imported animations from a game but they are flipped on the X axis, the character is left handed when he should be right handed, and its doing that on all animations that I import from the game
IS there a way to flip entire animations (so on multiple frames), multiple animations, without breaking them? In the best way possible
My goal is to then import those animations to unreal engine to retarget them on a character
I found multiple ways but they aren't perfect,
First one, I parented my armature to an empty scaled X-1, its the easiest way to do
Second I scaled the armature X-1, its good and I dont have inverted normals (on my character) in blender but it is inverted in Unreal
Third way, i scaled the root bone X-1, in blender the normals are inverted but not in Unreal Engine (so weird)
At the end it gives me weird animations when I retarget, I cant have clean animations, and idk what is causing those problems
So Id like a clean skeleton with clean animations
I tried to retarget those animations from my "dirty" skeleton to a new one (from rigify for example) with the rokoko addon but the retargeted animations in blender are broken too

If anyone could help me on some of my problems, or give me some ressources that could help me, would be very cool!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chaning animation is a pain, bc. you only want to invert some of the rotations and finding them per bone, will take ages. However:
[image]

These are the import options for fbx (right hand side of the file list). Since I don't know your model, I can't test it, but enable manual orientation and try different forward options. I'd start with positive Z.

Comment: Yeah I know that but it doesnt change anything interesting in my case, just the orientation of the whole armature, it doesnt flip the bones on one axis, it just rotates it

Comment: one desperate move could be to scale the armature to (-1, 1, 1)

Comment: Yeah I just put an empty with a scale X -1 but I wanted another clean solution

Comment: best of luck, maybe you'll find something when you search for left-handed coordinate system conversion in general